# How does a free particle evolve in QFT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, propagator

Say, there's a state $|p\rangle$. Acting on it with the Hamiltonian gives:

$$\sum_{p'} h\omega_{p'} a_{p'}^{\dagger}a_{p'} |p\rangle=h\omega_p |p\rangle$$

This indicates that the evolution should be:

$$e^{-\frac{i}{h} Ht} |p\rangle=e^{-i\omega_p t}|p\rangle$$

Is this it? This is so far no different from how free particles evolve in non relativistic quantum mechanics.

But there is another way to evolve states which conflicts with the above: The Feynman propagator. According to the momentum-space Feynman propagator, the state propagates according to the formula:

$$\frac{1}{2\omega_p} e^{-i\omega_p t}|p\rangle$$

This is different from the other one by a factor of $\frac{1}{2\omega_p}$. And this is also non-unitary because of that same factor.

Which one is correct? I think the first one is correct, and that the Feynman propagator should only be used in calculating interaction amplitudes. It has no relevance in the free theory. But then again, I keep reading that the Feynman propagator is the "probability that a particle travels from one spacetime point to another". What does that even mean? Is it that this phrase is talking about virtual particles, and hence Feynman propagator only has relevance when virtual particles exist, i.e. in interacting theories?

Comment: Hint: try evolving a particle by $t_1+t_2$ by evolving it by $t_1$ first and $t_2$ next. A consistent expression for the evolution operator would form a 1-parametric group, that is, $U(t_1+t_2) = U(t_2) U(t_1)$. The denominator is most likely due to a different normalization convention for the state $|p>$ (remember that states are rays, so for all nonzero $k \in \mathbb{C}$ and any state $|p>$, $k |p>$ is the same physical state).

Comment: The former expression is obviously correct and the latter is obviously not, but it's not because the Feynman propagator is somehow unsuitable for describing free theory (it is). OP has just made a mistake in the calculation. It's hard to pinpoint the exact origin of that mistake without having that calculation. However, it is almost definitely related to the "relativistic normalization" convention for the state $\left| p \right>$.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov You mean we should redefine $\frac{1}{2\omega_p}|p\rangle =|p\rangle$ in the second formula? But even then, the full Feynman propagator also has a modulus in the exponential : $\int \frac{1}{2\omega_p} e^{-i\omega_p |t-t_0|} |p\rangle \langle p| d^3p$. This modulus makes it different from the usual Schrodinger equation propagator.

Comment: You should give the full calculation of the evolution operator extracted from the Feynman propagator. Remember that $D(x-y) = \left< 0 \right| T \phi(x) \phi(y) \left| 0 \right>$ by definition. If you correctly do the Fourier transform and take care of all the creation and annihilation operators, you will pass to the matrix elements of the evolution operator on single-particle states with sharp momentum eigenvalues, and those would not contain the $1/(2 \omega_p)$ factor.

Comment: Yeah, it is customary to define $\left| p \right> = \sqrt{2 \omega_p} a_p^{\dagger} \left| 0 \right>$. Note that with that definition the matrix elements of a unitary operator between $\left< p \right|$ and $\left| p \right>$ are not unitary numbers (because the basis isn't orthonormal), which is the shenanigans going on with your question, I suspect.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov But what about the modulus $|t-t_0|$? Schrodinger evolution does not have that

Comment: Well the comparison between the evolution operator and the Feynman propagator is only valid for $t>t_0$, as the time ordering symbol indicates.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov I don't understand. The $\frac{1}{2\omega_p}$ naturally shows up in many calculations. For example, it naturally shows up in the result of the path integral of the free particle action. It shows up without assuming any conventions. It's not just a convention factor. Also, which propagator are we supposed to use for backward time evolution, Feynman or Schrodinger? They both conflict in backward time evolution in the sign of the exponential.

Comment: You should bite the bullet and do the honest math here. I understand it can be tedious, but it’s also a good way to learn. I guarantee you that your factor of $1/(2 \omega_p)$ will not appear in the derived evolution operator, and if somehow you think it does, post your calculation here and I will point out the mistake in it. W.r.t. negative time — Feynman propagator coincides with the matrix element of the evolution operator for positive time only (as is evident from the definition). To get negative time you can use the fact that the evolution operator is unitary and take its conjugate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138839/discussion-between-ryder-rude-and-prof-legolasov).